# reservoir cladding without WRB insulation options

Tags: insulation, garage

We’d like to air-seal and insulate our garage walls. We are in zone 5. The current configuration is brick veneer, 1" air gap, unprotected plywood sheathing, then 2x4 framing.  We will heat and cool the garage.  We’d like to get the highest r-value that we can. My understanding is that when the brick veneer gets wet and heated, it can result in vapor drive into the plywood.  The plywood is currently able to dry to the interior.  My concern is that if I use a vapor semi-impermeable or vapor impermeable insulation, the plywood will no longer be able to dry to the interior, potentially causing issues.  What are my options to insulate? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is there anywhere that the 1" air gap can vent to? If so, I'd think that any moisture that makes it through the brick and into/on to the wood would be able to evaporate through that venting.